# I'm employed with a good salary - when should I file for unemployment?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, unemployment

Due to the current pandemic & its economic effects my employer has recently cut back on salary by ~6%. Personally this has not caused any harm, but I want to be prepared in case things get worse in the future (impossible to know).

That said, given that my finances are presently fine I have absolutely no desire to actually accept any sort of public benefits right now, even if technically I would be eligible for them. That wouldn't seem right given how strapped the whole system is. However I do want to avoid disadvantaging myself in the future in some way if the situation gets much worse - like losing my job entirely.

So I am wondering if now is the time to make some sort of formal application to just to "register myself in the system"? ie, so that my history is accurately dated. Does this make any sense and/or is it necessary?

Location: New York State, USA

Comment: You don't need to do anything until you are *actually* unemployed. You are already registered as employed, and part of your employer's expenses likely include paying a tax on your salary that funds the general unemployment fund.

Comment: You had a work contract with a salary in it, didn't you? And you just accepted that your employer changes that contract to your disadvantage without negotiating? It's not your employers choice how much they are willing to pay you. It's a bilateral agreement.

Comment: @chepner that's pretty much the answer, add to that any CARE act adjustments to the requirements that might apply and it'd be quite complete.

Comment: @Philipp What law do you refer to where you state " benefits the law says you are entitled to". Is there a jurisdiction or circumstance where UI kicks in after a salary or hours reduction, but the person is still employed?  (I am not aware of this, but would like to learn if so)

Comment: @user662852 I was referring to whatever law OP was referring to when they wrote "no desire to actually accept any sort of public benefits right now, even if technically I would be eligible for them". I trust them to know their local welfare laws better than I do.

Comment: There is more to collecting unemployment benefits than just being out of a job. You also need to be actively looking for work, and you need to accept the first legitimate job offer. I suggest starting with general unemployment benefits research.